# All GET variables empty in laravel application with correct config

Tags: php, nginx

I'm experiencing something really strange. All my request variables are empty. In my index.php file I do the following:

`var_dump($_REQUEST); die();`

Which results in an empty array when firing `myapp.dev/test?query=val

My nginx config looks like:

```
server {
  listen                *:80;

  server_name           animekyun.dev ;
  client_max_body_size 8m;

  root /var/www/animekyun/public;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/pvf5a8g97whg.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/pvf5a8g97whg.error.log;

  location / {

    root  /var/www/animekyun/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;


  }
  location ~ \.php$ {

    root  /var/www/animekyun/public;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php /index.php$is_args$args;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_param ENV local;

  }
  sendfile off;
}
```

Another vhost with the exact same config (except `server_name`, `root` etc) does work. I don't know where else to search to fix this issue. It's not an issue in Laravel since the request is empty at the beginning of the `index.php` file.

I also tried

```
try_files $uri $uri/ index.php /index.php?$query_string;
```

Pointers are welcome since I don't know how else I should debug this.

EDIT:
It seems that this occurs as soon as I visit URI's with pretty urls. So this works:

```
index.php?get=something
```

but this does not

```
myapp.dev/someroute/?get=something
```

Comment: Nginx needs some other additional protocol for serving dynamic HTML, like uWSGI protocol, for example http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/PHP.html. Perhaps someother better protocol is available

Comment: Never seen that nor have I ever used that. It works fine on all other vhosts. This one just screws up.